# Angular routerlink using semicolon instead of question mark, url not behaving as expected

Tags: angular, url, routes

I have the following button in my code:

```html
<button [routerLink]="['/answerslist', {id: applicant.id} ]" label="View Interview"></button>
```

Corresponding to the following route:

```js
{ path: 'answerslist', component: AnswersListComponent },
```

I am expecting the URL to turn up as following:
http://localhost:4200/answerslist?id=member2

However I am getting this when clicking on the button:
http://localhost:4200/answerslist;id=member2

(Semicolon instead of question mark)

And as a result, the code doesn't work properly. I am retrieving the parameter for later use as follows:

```js
  getUser(){
    this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(
      (params) => {
        const id = params['id'];
        if (id) { 
          this.currentUser = id;
        }
        else{
          console.log('id not passed'); //this is what currenlty gets printed
        }
      });
  }
```

So I need a way to construct the URL with a question mark, not a semicolon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pls try this

```
< button [routerLink]="['answerslist']" [queryParams]="{ id: applicant.id }"></button >
```

more info can be found on https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink